# What is the correct reading of 心底?

Tags: words, readings

The word 心底 has 2 readings which are しんそこ and しんてい. Both seem to be interchangeable with one another. Searching online has this page popping up. https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10112707945. To quote it directly, the difference is explained as, "「しんそこ」 は思っている状態、「しんてい」 は思っているそのこと。". So to phrase it differently, しんそこ is used to describe a state of thinking whereas しんてい is used to emphasize a thing about thinking? Forgive me if I got it wrong or misinterpreted it but the answer doesn't really seem to explain the proper usage or reading of the word to me.

Answer (score 1):

You've included a link to Chiebukuro but that site actually links the more helpful kotobank definitions [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BF%83%E5%BA%95-538259).

First, both readings are correct. It isn't a case of one or the other being right or wrong. There *are* times when Japanese words can have the exact same kanji and be read in different ways, with one being considered 'correct' - this is called 慣用読み ("reading of a word or kanji using its customary pronunciation (which is not necessarily correct)" - EDICT). A word like 貼付 would be an example of that.

However, in the case of 心底, it appears that each reading can convey a slightly different semantic nuance.  For example, the kotobank definitions list しんそこ as referring to feelings and emotions:

> 心底から感服する　to admire someone from the bottom of your heart. *(**feelings/emotion**)*

On the other hand, しんてい seems to refer the actual thoughts that someone has, thoughts that are deeply believed.

> 心底を見抜く to see through to what someone really thinks in their heart. *(**thoughts**)*

In some ways, the distinction is just academic. I would say that there isn't really much difference between the feelings in your heart and the thoughts that arise from those feelings. It seems like a trivial distinction, in my opinion.

In any case, both readings of 心底 are correct. They convey slightly different meanings, at least according to some sources.